# Which encoding failure did encode "vóór" into "v3/43/4r"?

Tags: encoding

A while ago, I saw the text ["v3/43/4r"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22v3/43/4r%22) in a document.

I know it comes from "vóór" (the [acute accent emphasises in Dutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent#Emphasis)), and wonder which encoding failure was applied to get this wrong.

Comment: Strange, 3/4 isn't something that makes a lot of intuitive sense to me

Comment: I think it is a single-byte code page issue, but I wonder which one (: ¾ usually is 0xBE in single-byte codepages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some time ago I've written a program that semi-automatically makes this analysis (maybe I'll publish it some time...) and here it is the result, with a bit of imagination:

- ó: is U+00F3, and occupies the same codepoint (0xF3) in a lot of different encodings (most ISO-8859-* and most western Windows-*).
- In CP850 the codepint 0xF3 is ¾ (U+00BE), that is the three-quarters character. It is the same in other, less used, codepages (CP775, CP856, CP857, CP858).
- The ¾ is sometimes transliterated to 3/4 when the character is not directly available.

And there you are! "vóór" -> "v¾¾r" -> "v3/43/4r".

The first part (ó -> ¾) is the usual corruption of ANSI vs. OEM codepages in the Western Windows versions (in my country ANSI=Windows-1252, OEM=CP850). You can see it easily creating a file with NOTEPAD, writing `vóór` and dumping it in a command prompt with `type`.

Comment: Thanks! The infamous CP850 strikes again (: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850

Comment: As an addition: Unicode codepoint 00BE in various code Pages. 0xBE in 1252, 1256, 1254, 1255, 1256, 1257, 1258, 6937, 8859-1, 8859-8, 8859-9, 8859-13, UTI-T6.1; 0xF3 in 775, 850, 857, 858; 0xAB in 863; 0xB9 in EBCDIC 037, 285, 500, 1047. Most from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)#Comparison_table